# How is this interactive website made?

Tags: user-interface, web, cross-platform, interactive

I am trying to make a website similar to this and I'd like to know how [this](https://realtimeboard.com/app/) website was made. The website is also run on desktop and has a mobile app too so there's no HTML or anything in the back end.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Wappalyzer to identify the technologies used for this Website.

https://www.wappalyzer.com/

[Result for https://realtimeboard.com/signup/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN31J.png)

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned you can use https://www.wappalyzer.com/ or http://builtwith.com to know the technologies used, further more you can view the webpage source or use the inspect element tool to have a better idea of what is going on. and ofcourse there is HTML used in that page whether it was automatically generated or manually